# Gson Removing Timestamp From Date while Conversion

Tags: java, gson, java-11

I am using to convert JSON String to POJO Class using Gson. In Pojo the attribute are of java.util.Date type. While gson maps Json String to Pojo objects it is removing timestamp.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S'Z'").create();
ClassBaseModel baseModel = gson.fromJson(request, ClassBaseModel.class);

Attribute Original Value in String Json is - "orderDate": "2021-12-01T07:16:31Z"
After It is converted into POJO - 2021-12-01
Expected is - 2021-12-01T07:16:31Z
```

I am not sure what wrong I am doing. Can somebody please point out.

Comment: Can you share the class `ClassBaseModel`. Please Add a [mcve]

Comment: How are you coming at the conclustion that it is remmoving time format? are you debugging to see `2021-12-01` or printing only date without time

Comment: And also please do not use `java.util.Date` anymore. This class is outdated since many years Use the newer `java.time` API

Answer (score 1):

While Deserializing you have to register deserializer type in gson using `registerTypeAdapter`

Here is how I have tried to do so, and also

Request class:

```java
class OrderInfoRequest {
    String orderDate;

    public OrderInfoRequest(String orderDate) {
        this.orderDate = orderDate;
    }
}
```

Main Mapper class

```java
class OrderInfo {
    OffsetDateTime orderDate;

    public OffsetDateTime getOrderDate() {
        return orderDate;
    }

    public void setOrderDate(OffsetDateTime orderDate) {
        this.orderDate = orderDate;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "OrderInfo{" +
                "orderDate=" + orderDate +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Sample code

```
public class DateMain {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            OrderInfoRequest orderInfoRequest = new OrderInfoRequest("2021-12-01T07:16:31Z");
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                    .registerTypeAdapter(OffsetDateTime.class, (JsonDeserializer<OffsetDateTime>) (json, typeOfT, context) -> OffsetDateTime.parse(json.getAsString(), DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME))
                    .create();

            String requestJson = gson.toJson(orderInfoRequest);
            System.out.println("Request json");
            System.out.println(requestJson);
            OrderInfo orderInfo = gson.fromJson(requestJson, OrderInfo.class);
            System.out.println("After parsing pojo");
            System.out.println(orderInfo);

            System.out.println("printing full date: " + orderInfo.orderDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd, hh:mm")));

        }
    }
```

Also as told by @Jens avoid using java.util.Date class from today onwards if you haven't.